# strongswan govici: unmarshall child SA struct

Tags: go, marshalling, strongswan, vici

I'm starting to use the Strongswan `govici` API to control IPsec, following the general pattern I found at https://github.com/strongswan/govici/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md.

It's working except that I'm unable to set a connection's childSA's `map_in` and `map_out` fields.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/k0kubun/pp/v3"
    "github.com/strongswan/govici/vici"
)

func main() {
    type childSA struct {
        markIn  string `vici:"mark_in"`
        markOut string `vici:"mark_out"`
    }
    type viciConnection struct {
        LocalAddrs  []string            `vici:"local_addrs"`
        RemoteAddrs []string            `vici:"remote_addrs"`
        Children    map[string]*childSA `vici:"children"`
    }

    vc := viciConnection{
        LocalAddrs:  []string{"1.1.1.1"},
        RemoteAddrs: []string{"2.2.2.2"},
        Children: map[string]*childSA{
            "onlyChild": &childSA{
                markIn:  "4/0xffffffff",
                markOut: "4",
            },
        },
    }

    c, err := vici.MarshalMessage(vc)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        return
    }

    pp.Default.SetColoringEnabled(false)
    fmt.Printf("Marshalled message: %s\n", pp.Sprint(c))
}
```

Output:

```
Marshalled message: &vici.Message{
  keys: []string{
    "local_addrs",
    "remote_addrs",
    "children",
  },
  data: map[string]interface {}{
    "children": &vici.Message{
      keys: []string{
        "onlyChild",
      },
      data: map[string]interface {}{
        "onlyChild": &vici.Message{
          keys: []string{},
          data: map[string]interface {}{},
        },
      },
    },
    "local_addrs": []string{
      "1.1.1.1",
    },
    "remote_addrs": []string{
      "2.2.2.2",
    },
  },
}
```

Under `onlyChild` I expect to see `mark_in` and `mark_out` fields, in the `keys` and `data` sections, but they're missing.

Run it here: https://goplay.tools/snippet/WRoelsjbf9M

Comment: Export the `markIn` and `markOut` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BurakSerdar: capitalize the field names so that they're exported fields:

```
type childSA struct {
    MarkIn  string `vici:"mark_in"`
    MarkOut string `vici:"mark_out"`
}
```